# Laplace transform of natural logarithm of a function

Tags: logarithms, laplace-transform

Let's assume that we have a function $i(t)$ and it has a Laplace transform  $I(s)$. Can we calculate the Laplace transform of $\ln(i(t))$ in terms of $I(s)$ ?

Comment: We are in the continuous domain

Comment: Intuitively, I would say that there is no connection.

Answer (score 1):

Take $i(t)=t$, and note that $\mathcal{L}\{t\}=\frac{1}{s^2}=I(s)$

And $\mathcal{L}\{\log t\}=-\frac{\log s+\gamma}{s}$. As you can see there's no way to write one in terms of the other

Comment: Why not? Here we have $\sqrt{\frac{1}{I(s)}}=s$ so if we substitute it we get an expression.

Comment: I dont think that the expression $-\frac{\log \frac{1}{\sqrt{I(s)}}+\gamma}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{I(s)}}}$ is to useful...

Comment: Expression can change. I need an expression no matter how ugly it is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking through examples, one could ask instead this question:

Given $\mathcal{L} \{ i(t)\}=I(s)$, what's $\mathcal{L} \{ f(i(t))\}$?

And you should approach it by the deffinition

$$\mathcal{L} \{ f(i(t))\} = \int_0^{+\infty} f(i(t))e^{-st} dt$$ and see the what one could do and what conditions impose to $f$.
Sure, there could be examples of both $f$ and $i$ that gives "nice" results, but it's not the general case.

Comment: Exactly. Do we have a result in the literature that is already generated or is this question open?

Comment: At least for me, it's an open question and haven't seen such properties or results in any literature